# Protocol Buffers: toByteString() returns empty ByteString

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have the following message type in my project:

```
message KeyValue {

    oneof content {
        StringKeyValue string_key_value = 1;
        // ...
    }

}

message StringKeyValue {
    string key = 1;
    string value = 2;
}
```

And this generic type to transfer any kind of objects.

```
message Anything {
    bytes value = 1;
    // ...
}
```

And the following collection, in which I would like to transfer a number of serialized the KeyValue messages as Anything.

```
message List {

    oneof content {
        AnythingList anything_list = 1;
        // ...
    }
}

message AnythingList {
    repeated com.mycompany.Anything value = 1;
}
```

That means I have to convert my KeyValue contining a StringKeyValue to a ByteString when adding that to a serialized List like follows. This works fine in one of my projects, but only contains an empty ByteString in an other project although neither the StringKeyValue, nor the KeyValue is empty.

```
AnythingList.Builder keyValueListBuilder = AnythingList.newBuilder();
keyValueListBuilder.addValue(Anything.newBuilder()
    .setValue(KeyValue.newBuilder()
        .setStringKeyValue(StringKeyValue.newBuilder()
            .setKey("someKey")
            .setValue("someValue").build())
        .build().toByteString())
    .build());
```

The projects' dependencies can not be the cause of this problem, because after using the exact same ones in both projects, the above code still refused to work in the one, in which it didn't work at the beginning.
Sadly I couldn't find any explanation why I get different results. Is there anything I'm missing in my source code or configuration?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I changed something in the project, which wasn't related to this issue at all and ran everything a couple of times. Now it seems to work.
Sadly, I have no idea what the cause was and how I solved it, becuase, like I wrote I changed something not at all related to this problem.